# Does Visual Studio Code have a build or run task on document save?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to have VSC build when a document or documents are saved?

Or run a build task?

Comment: which language?

Comment: @AvinKavish Any language. But in my case I would like to run a build task when saving Apache Royale MXML, ActionScript as, and Electron main.js files

Comment: VSCode is mostly a glorified text editor, it doesn't have file watching features, unless you write a custom extension yourself. The file watchers usually come from the build tools relevant to your enviornment. For eg:- `dotnet watch`, `nodemon`, ``